Why does the textfield not display the proper value, when i select it? (unity custom inspector)
I'm having trouble with my custom unity editor.
I have created a TextArea in my editor script, but it acts strange when i try to change the value via code, while also selecting it.

textEditor.text = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(textEditor.text, GUILayout.MinHeight(100));

The yellow buttons at the bottom are set up to add a string of text to the textarea. For example, "bold" adds "<b> </b>".
But when I press the buttons, the text does not show up in the TextArea. I know the problem isn't the code that adds the text, as the added text eventually appears in the TextArea, once I deselect the TextArea.
The button calls a function called "AddFormat" like this: textEditor.AddFormat(textEditor.textFormats[i]);. Inside my class is the AddFormat function, that just says text += _format.openingTag + " " + _format.closingTag;
I have tried looking for some way to either automatically deselect the TextArea or redraw the editor all together. I also tried Repaint().

What is the code that runs when the buttons are pressed? What have you tried?

I have tried the Repaint() method and the SceneView.RepaintAll() inside the editor.
The button calls a function called "AddFormat" like this: textEditor.AddFormat(textEditor.textFormats[i]);
Inside my class is the AddFormat function, that just says text += _format.openingTag + " " + _format.closingTag;
I hope that helps

https://discussions.unity.com/t/textarea-not-properly-updating/26574 jonas-echterhoff suggests: "While you are editing a TextArea or TextField, changes to the source string will not be picked up by the text editor. You could try removing Focus from the TextArea when you want to change the text by calling:
GUIUtility.keyboardControl = 0;
GUIUtility.hotControl = 0; "

@Ruzihm That works perfectly! thank yo so much.
(Do you know how i close this question?)

Feel free to accept the answer i posted below and that'll mark the question as having been answered

jonas-echterhoff suggests:

While you are editing a TextArea or TextField, changes to the source
string will not be picked up by the text editor. You could try
removing Focus from the TextArea when you want to change the text by
calling:
GUIUtility.keyboardControl = 0;
GUIUtility.hotControl = 0;



In order to afterwards also regain the focus (if required) you can/have to use some quite dirty hacks

@derHugo Actually you can use GUI.SetNextControlName to give a control a name and use GUI.FocusControl to set the focus to a named control.

@Bunny83 I was just wondering whether this is enough to set both properties correctly the above snippet resets

Yes, setting hotControl and keyboardControl to 0 should deselect / unfocus the TextField, at least the next frame / update. The actual issue is that Unity uses a TextEditor instance which does handle the actual text editing. GetStateObject will create or return the specifed object for a given control id. It uses lazy creation. IMGUI is mostly stateless but those state objects are an exception.
